# QEMU outside gateway

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, qemu

I've created two instances of CentOS6.5 (KVM) using Virtual Manager and I'm able to ping google.com, yahoo.com,etc... However the ip addresses for the instances are 192.168.0.* and the machine that they reside on has the gateway 192.168.0.1
I want the instances to connect to the same gateway (1.2.3.1) as the computer that is hosting the VM's and get addresses such as 1.2.3.*.

I'm new to networking any pointers would help. I would the issue above would require updating the route tables but not sure how it would happen. Hopefully the attached picture might help explain the layout better.

Thanks in advance :).

[image: Layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to bridge the physical interface with the guest interfaces.

http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Networking#Bridged_networking_.28aka_.22shared_physical_device.22.29

This describes how to make the changes in libvirt which is probably backing your KVM.

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_a_CentOS_6_KVM_Networked_Bridge_Interface

This is tailored for Virtual Manager, and likely a lot easier. If you can I'd recommend learning the libvirt side of things so you're more familiar with what's going on.

It's important to note you'll be creating a bridge with your physical interface, and then point your guests to that bridge. Once configured you'll be able to use the network as usual. The most common mistake I've seen is assigning the bridge to the physical interface, or assigning the guest to use the physical interface instead of the bridge. Virtual manager will likely catch both of these, but its good to watch out for these things.

A few things to remember about bridged interfaces:

1) The guest is essentially on your network, meaning you should treat it as such and run any security or monitoring software right on it. You don't want the host running the guest and then processing everything again.

2) You'll hit the cap on that interface pretty quickly if you're not careful.